# Template won't be rendered in Meteor FlowRouter

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I need your help to figure out what's wrong with my code.
I have a `HomeLayout` devided to 3 sections;

1. header
2. side
3. **main**

[image]

I have a **conversation list** ; it will be rendered in the main section and it contain a **subsection** called `One_Conversation` : when I click on conversation it's rendered 
[image]

well right here it's ok : my problem that when I click  on another conversation , the template won't be rendered

this is my code :
**/routes.js**

```
FlowRouter.route('/conversation', {
    name: 'Conversation',

    action(){
        BlazeLayout.render('HomeLayout', {side: 'Messages', main: 'Conversation_list'});
    }
});
FlowRouter.route('/conversation/:idConversation', {
    name: 'oneConversation',
    action(){
        BlazeLayout.render('HomeLayout', {side: 'Messages', main: 'Conversation_list', conversation: 'One_conversation'});
    }
});
```

**/HomeLayout.html**

```
<template name="HomeLayout">

        <div class="app header-fixed sidebar-fixed aside-menu-fixed aside-menu-hidden">
            {{> Header}}

            <div class="app-body">
                <div class="sidebar">
                    {{> Template.dynamic template=side }}
                </div>
                <main class="main">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        {{> Template.dynamic template=main }}
                    </div>
                </main>

            </div>
            {{> Footer}}
        </div>
</template>
```

**/Conversation_list.html**

```
<template name="Conversation_list">
<div class="messages">
////code
////code
////...
</div>
 <conversation class="content">
            {{> Template.dynamic template=conversation }}
        </conversation>
</template>
```

and finnaly in my `Conversation_list.events` when I click  to conversation

```
FlowRouter.go('/conversation/:idConversation', {idConversation:this._id});
```

this is `/OneConversation.html` Template

```
<template name="One_conversation">
    {{#with oneConversation}}

            <div class="contact-profile">
                {{#if isDefault}}
                    <img src="{{contact.profile_pic}}" alt="" />
                    <p>{{contact.first_name}} {{contact.last_name}}</p>

                {{else}}
                    <img src="http://emilcarlsson.se/assets/harveyspecter.png" alt="" />
                    <p>{{contactLiveChat.first_name}} {{contactLiveChat.last_name}}</p>
                {{/if}}
                <div class="social-media">
                    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="messages">
                {{#each allMessagesOfConversation}}
                    <ul>
                        {{#if isFirst}}

                            <li class="replies">
                                <img src="http://emilcarlsson.se/assets/harveyspecter.png" alt="" />
                                <p>{{message}} </p>
                            </li>
                        {{else}}

                            <li class="sent">
                                <img src="{{contactM.profile_pic}}" alt="" />
                                <p>{{message}}</p>
                            </li>
                        {{/if}}
                    </ul>
                {{/each}}
            </div>


            <div class="message-input">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Write your message..." />
                    <i class="fa fa-paperclip attachment" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <button class="submit"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

and this is `/OneConversation.js`

```
import { Template } from ‘meteor/templating’;

import ‘./One_conversation.html’;
import {Meteor} from “meteor/meteor”;
var idConversation=’’;
var typeConversation=’’;
var token=’’;
var psid=’’;
Template.One_conversation.onCreated(function One_conversationOnCreated() {
idConversation = FlowRouter.getParam(“idConversation”);
// typeConversation= Session.get(‘typeConversation’);
//
//
// token= Session.get(‘token’);
// psid= Session.get(‘psid’);
// console.log("OneConversation psid: ",psid);
// console.log("OneConversation token: ",token);
//
// psid= FlowRouter.getParam(“psid”);
// console.log("OneConversation psid liveChat: ",psid);

Meteor.subscribe('allConversations');
Meteor.subscribe('allMessages');
Meteor.subscribe('allContacts');
Meteor.subscribe('allHotels');
Meteor.subscribe('allImMessenger');
});

Template.One_conversation.rendered = function () {

};

Template.One_conversation.helpers({
allMessagesOfConversation: function() {

    return Messages.find({idConversation: idConversation},{sort: {createdAt: 1}}).map(function(message) {

        if (message.typeMessage ==="1") {
            message.isFirst=true;
            return message;
        }else {
            return message;

        }
    });

},
oneConversation: function() {

    return Conversations.findOne({_id: idConversation});


},
});

Template.One_conversation.events({
‘click .submit’(event,instance) {

    const message = $(".message-input input").val();
    if($.trim(message) === '') {
        return false;
    }

    if(Session.get('typeConversation') ==='facebook'){
        Meteor.call("sendMessage",Session.get('token'),Session.get('psid'),message, function (er) {
            if (er) {
                console.log("send message problem");
                console.log(er);
            } else {
                console.log("message sended successfully");
                $(".message-input input").val('');
            }
        });
    }else{
        var newMessageInfo = {
            idSender: Session.get('psid'),
            message: message,
            type: "liveChat",
            createdAt: new Date(),
            idConversation: Session.get('idConversation'),
            status: "seen",
            typeMessage: '1'
        };
        Meteor.call('insertMessages', newMessageInfo, function (er) {
            if (er) {
                console.log("insert problem");
                console.log(er);

            } else {
                console.log("message added successfully", "success");
                $(".message-input input").val('');

            }

        });
    }
},
});
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try `FlowRouter.go(\`/conversation/{this._id}\`);`

Comment: it can't be done like that, the id in the URL is changing without problem; my problem is that the template is not rendered after the url is changed

Comment: Where are you loading the data into the template? There should be a `.find()` somewhere…

Comment: ok i will edit my post and add the missing code

Comment: I tried but there is no way to reproduce this. The example code has many helpers referenced in the html that have not been posted with the js code and there are also no publications and collections added. The source of error could be anywhere, ranging from typos in template naming to wrong pub/sub (see the `#with` as suspicious here). If you want this solved you may first check on all code that is dependent on the problem. Maybe this already leads you to the solution yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's fixed , my problem was in the **idConversation** ;

i set the id of the conversation in a session **conversationList.events** and get it in the **oneConversation** Helper so the code become like this

```
/Conversation_list.js

import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import './conversationList.html';
import {Meteor} from "meteor/meteor";

    Template.conversationList.onCreated(function conversationListOnCreated() {
        Meteor.subscribe('allConversations');
        Meteor.subscribe('allMessages');
        Meteor.subscribe('allContacts');
        Meteor.subscribe('allHotels');
        Meteor.subscribe('allImMessenger');
    });
    var psid="";
    var token="";

    Template.conversationList.rendered = function () {
    };

    Template.conversationList.helpers({
        toUpperCase: function(str) {
            return str.toUpperCase();
        },
        allMessagesOfConversation: function() {
            return Messages.find({idConversation: Session.get('conversationId')},{sort: {createdAt: 1}}).map(function(message) {
                if (message.typeMessage ==="1") {
                    message.isFirst=true;
                    return message;
                }else {
                    return message;
                }
            });
        },
        oneConversation: function() {
            return Conversations.findOne({_id: Session.get('conversationId')});
        },

        allConversations: function() {
            return Conversations.find({idHotel: Hotels.findOne({contractId: Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId()}).profile.contractId})._id,archived:false},{sort: {createdAt: -1}}).map(function(conversation, index) {
                if (index === 0) {
                    conversation.isFirst = true;
                }
                if(conversation.typeConversation === 'facebook'){
                    conversation.isDefault = true;
                }
                return conversation;
            });
        },
    });

    Template.conversationList.events({
        'click #archive'(event){
            Meteor.call('archiveConversation',Session.get('idOneConversation'),function (err) {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }else{
                    FlowRouter.go('/conversation');
                }
            })
        },
        'click .contact'(event,instance) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if($("#contact_active").hasClass("active")){
                $("#contact_active").removeClass("active");
                $("#contact").addClass("active");
            }else{
                $("#contact").removeClass("active");
                $("#contact_active").addClass("active");

            }
            Session.set('typeConversation',this.typeConversation);
            if(this.typeConversation === 'facebook'){
                const pageId = this.idPage;
                console.log(pageId);
                token = ImMessenger.findOne({pageId: pageId}).pageAccessToken;
                Session.set('token', token);


                psid = this.contact().idFacebook;
                Session.set('psid', psid);

                Session.set('conversationId', this._id);

            }else{
                psid = this.contactLiveChat()._id;
                Session.set('idContactLiveChat', psid);
                Session.set('conversationId', this._id);
            }

            FlowRouter.go('/conversation/:idConversation', {idConversation:this._id});
            Session.set('idOneConversation',this._id);

        },
        'click .profile-img'(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#status-options").toggleClass("active");
        },
        'click .expand-button'(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#status-options").toggleClass("active");
        },
        'click .status-options ul li'(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#profile-img").removeClass();
            $("#status-online").removeClass("active");
            $("#status-away").removeClass("active");
            $("#status-busy").removeClass("active");
            $("#status-offline").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");

            if($("#status-online").hasClass("active")) {
                $("#profile-img").addClass("online");
            } else if ($("#status-away").hasClass("active")) {
                $("#profile-img").addClass("away");
            } else if ($("#status-busy").hasClass("active")) {
                $("#profile-img").addClass("busy");
            } else if ($("#status-offline").hasClass("active")) {
                $("#profile-img").addClass("offline");
            } else {
                $("#profile-img").removeClass();
            };
            $("#status-options").removeClass("active");
        },
    });
```

and this is

```
/oneConversation.js

import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import './oneConversation.html';
import {Meteor} from "meteor/meteor";
var idOneConversation='';
var typeConversation='';
var token='';
var psid='';
Template.oneConversation.onCreated(function oneConversationOnCreated() {
    idOneConversation = FlowRouter.getParam("idConversation");
    Session.set('idOneConversation',idOneConversation);

    Meteor.subscribe('allConversations');
    Meteor.subscribe('allMessages');
    Meteor.subscribe('allContacts');
    Meteor.subscribe('allHotels');
    Meteor.subscribe('allImMessenger');
});

Template.oneConversation.rendered = function () {

};

Template.oneConversation.helpers({
    allMessagesOfConversation: function() {

        return Messages.find({idConversation: Session.get('idOneConversation')},{sort: {createdAt: 1}}).map(function(message) {

            if (message.typeMessage ==="1") {
                message.isFirst=true;
                return message;
            }else {
                return message;

            }
        });

    },
    oneConversation: function() {

        return Conversations.findOne({_id: Session.get('idOneConversation')});


    },
});

Template.oneConversation.events({
    'click #archive'(event){
        Meteor.call('archiveConversation',Session.get('idOneConversation'),function (err) {

        })
    },
    'click .submit'(event,instance) {

        const message = $(".message-input input").val();
        if($.trim(message) === '') {
            return false;
        }

        if(Session.get('typeConversation') ==='facebook'){
            Meteor.call("sendMessage",Session.get('token'),Session.get('psid'),message, function (er) {
                if (er) {
                    console.log("send message problem");
                    console.log(er);
                } else {
                    console.log("message sended successfully");
                    $(".message-input input").val('');
                }
            });
        }else{
            var newMessageInfo = {
                idSender: Session.get('idContactLiveChat'),
                message: message,
                type: "liveChat",
                createdAt: new Date(),
                idConversation: Session.get('idOneConversation'),
                status: "seen",
                typeMessage: '1'
            };
            Meteor.call('insertMessages', newMessageInfo, function (er) {
                if (er) {
                    console.log("insert problem");
                    console.log(er);

                } else {
                    console.log("message added successfully", "success");
                    $(".message-input input").val('');

                }

            });
        }
    },
});
```